# Maria db false size

Tags: mariadb, centos

I am using maria db on a centos 7.5 VM with 150G disk.
Df command shows me 30G free. I've 2 large dbs about 20G each.
That is a sum of 40G. I have 3 smaller dbs let's say 20G more, so I have a total of max 80G.
Where are the other 50G of my disk space?

Comment: Where the sizes are taken from? The size occupied on the disk in always greater than the data size. Sometimes it can be greater dramatically...

Comment: Please provide `SHOW TABLE STATUS` for the database.  And `ls -l` or `dir` of the directory where the database is stored.  Are you using InnoDB?  Did you delete lots of rows recently?  Were the tables created with `innodb_file_per_table = ON`?  Is the table Partitioned?

Comment: (In other words, there are lots of possible answers; we need more clues to explain your case.)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the actual table data files, here are some examples of other things that also take up disk space:

- Indexes
- [Log files](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/overview-of-mariadb-logs/):

  - [Binary log](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/binary-log/)
  - [InnoDB System tablespaces](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-system-tablespaces/)
  - InnoDB logs (redo log and undo log)
  - [Error log](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/error-log/)
  - Slow query log
  - Relay log
  - Other log files such as SQL error log

Note also that due to sparse files, the actually used/allocated disk size, e.g. as reported by `du`, may be larger than the sum of all the table data + index sizes as reported by MariaDB in queries such as:

```
SELECT table_schema, 
  sum((data_length+index_length)/1024/1024) AS MB
FROM information_schema.tables 
GROUP BY 1;
```